# There are two cache-control headers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

There are two cache-control settings in google chrome developer tools:

[image]

One of them, which I did set with .htaccess :

[image]

I have no idea about the other. I've searched all php files and could not find any header settings.
Other .htaccess files I have also look clean.
Does anyone have any experience what could cause this, and how can I prevent this?

PHP 8.1 - Apache 2.4.46 - Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The first one is probably resulting of session_start (see [session.cache_limiter](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.session-cache-limiter.php)). I think it is not a good idea to handle php files with this .htaccess/FilesMatch.